# update Multiple records in Publication list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, publicationlist

Currently we are struggling to retrieve multiple rows from Publication list. We have cloud page where we need to fetch all records with same email address and usubscribe them all from Publication List. All the functions(lookuprows, lookuporderedrows etc) we tried are all for Data Extensions. 
Anyone have idea to how retrieve multiple records from publication list?
Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but i strongly believe its either https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_publicationsubscriber.htm&type=5 or https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5 where you should search.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! we are using ampscript in the cloud page, so there must be some function who does this sort of thing.

Comment: LookUpRows on the Lists i just showed you?

Comment: [LookupRows("ENT._ListSubscribers","SubscriberKey","ListName","ABC_PL","EmailAddress",@sid)] Above is the function we tried to use but cloud page stops previewing.

Comment: Any idea here? how can i query Publication list using Ampscript to get multiple records satisfying a condition?

Comment: @Adam Spriggs could you please help here?

Answer (score 1):

It's late, but I guess this can be done

```
SET @Rows = LookupRows("_ListSubscribers","SubscriberKey", @Sub_ID, "ListType","Publication List","Column Name","Value")
```

You can choose from the following columns listed in [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5).

This will give you a set of rows which fall under your preference criteria. Then you can move forward according to your need.